# Error in independent variables models

Tags: regression, econometrics, instrumental-variables, measurement-error

I am trying to estimate a simple regression. One of my indpendent variable (income in the current year) cannot be fully observe: what I have is the income in the previous year and the information whether the income of this year is improved, worsen or unchanged compared to last year. So I have this categorical variable *z*=1 if the income improves, *z*=2 if the income worsens and *z*=3 if the income is unchanged.
The equation I want to estimate is:
\begin{equation}
y = \alpha + \beta \cdot (x + \delta ) + \epsilon
\end{equation}
with:
\begin{cases}
\delta > 0, &\text{if $z=1$}  \\
\delta < 0, &\text{if $z=2$}  \\
\delta = 0, &\text{if $z=3$}
\end{cases}
Alternatively:
\begin{equation}
y = \alpha + \beta \cdot (x \cdot \delta ) + \epsilon
\end{equation}
with:
\begin{cases}
\delta > 1, &\text{if $z=1$}  \\
\delta < 1, &\text{if $z=2$}  \\
\delta = 1, &\text{if $z=3$}
\end{cases}
What method do you suggest me for estimate (with a confidence interval) the parameter $\beta$?
I was thinking to instrumental variable, but the problem is that $z$ is correlated with the dependent variable.
Thank you

Comment: $z$ should be correlated with $y$, but it has to be only through $x$ and in no other way. Perhaps you meant that $z$ is also correlated with $\epsilon$?

Comment: I think $z$ is correlated to y because y is a self-assessed life satisfaction score. I don't know if it can be used as instrument (the fact that the income has improved or not I think it implies a correlation)

Comment: The easiest solution is to regress y on z for z=3 subsample. Otherwise, some sort of measurement error structural equation model would be the best route. Also, I assume $\delta_i$ varies across people?

Comment: Thank you Dimitriy. With the first suggestion, do you mean run 3 different equations (one for each $z$?). Second, do you have some reference for measuremenr error structural equation model? I am not very much expert. Yes, $\delta_i$ varies across people

Comment: No, I mean reg y x if z==1. The other two are biased by the measurement error and will have attenuated coefficients. On the SEM, this is sufficiently complicated with a partially latent covariate that I don’t know of a book or paper where this is covered. But this is pretty far from my area of expertise, so perhaps someone else can chime in.